# SQL Select using distinct and Cast

Tags: sql, select, casting, distinct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Select DISTINCT using CAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790953/sql-select-distinct-using-cast)

Let me try this one more time... I'm not a sql guy so please bear with me as I try to explain this...  I have a table called `t_recordkeepingleg` with three columns of data.  Column1 is named `LEGTRIPNUMBER` that happens to be a string that starts with the letter Q followed by 4 numbers.  I need to strip off the Q and convert the remaining 4 characters (numbers) to an integer.  Everyone with me so far?  Column2 of this table is named `LEGDATE`.  Column3 is named `LEGGROUP`.

Here's the input scenario

```
LEGTRIPNUMBER    LEGDATE      LEGGROUP
Q1001            08/12/12       0001
Q1001            09/15/12       0002
Q1002            09/01/12       0001
Q1002            09/08/12       0003
Q1002            09/09/12       0002
```

As you can see the input table has rows where `LEGTRIPNUMBER` occurs more than once.  I only want the first occurrence.

This is my current select statement - it works but returns all rows.

```
SELECT *, 
   CAST(
       substring("t_RecordkeepingLeg"."LEGTRIPNUMBER",2,4) as INT
   ) as Num_Trip_Num
   FROM   "1669"."dbo"."t_RecordkeepingLeg" "t_RecordkeepingLeg" 
   Where left "t_RecordkeepingLeg"."LEGTRIPNUMBER",1) = 'Q'
```

I want to modify this so that it only selects ONE occurance of the Qnnnn.  When the row gets selected I want to have `LEGDATE` and `LEGGROUP` available to me.    How do I do this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Can it be as simple as below? I've just added condiotion on leggroup being 0001

```
SELECT *,  
   CAST(substring("t_RecordkeepingLeg"."LEGTRIPNUMBER",2,4) as INT) as Num_Trip_Num 
 FROM   "1669"."dbo"."t_RecordkeepingLeg" "t_RecordkeepingLeg"  
 Where left ("t_RecordkeepingLeg"."LEGTRIPNUMBER",1) = 'Q'
    and "t_RecordkeepingLeg"."LEGGROUP"='0001'
```

Comment: I don't think so because I don't want all the leggroup=0001. I want the first occurance of LEGTRIPNUMBER and whatever is in legdate and leggroup.

Comment: SQL does not guarantee any particular row order, so the first occurence for you might not be the first for somebody else, depending on actual RDBMS and host of other factors.  Could you elaborate on context, what do you mean when you say 'first occurence'? Is it the one with earliest date on it?

Comment: If the column LEGTRIPNUMBER contains the value Q1001 more than once I only want one of them.. I don't care which one just one of them.  What if there is a column that contains a sequential number that is unique but not defined as a key? Would this help my situation?

Comment: If you do not care which one of the rows you want, then why not take one with leggroup=0001? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique primay key in your table you can do something like the below;

```
SELECT CAST(
   substring("t_RecordkeepingLeg"."LEGTRIPNUMBER",2,4) as INT
) as Num_Trip_Num
FROM   "1669"."dbo"."t_RecordkeepingLeg" "t_RecordkeepingLeg" 
Where "t_RecordkeepingLeg"."ID" In(
   Select Min("t_RecordkeepingLeg"."ID")
   From "1669"."dbo"."t_RecordkeepingLeg" "t_RecordkeepingLeg" 
   Where left ("t_RecordkeepingLeg"."LEGTRIPNUMBER",1) = 'Q'
   Group By "t_RecordkeepingLeg"."LEGTRIPNUMBER"
)
```

Comment: Sorry about the dupe post.. Obviously this is my first post... Not sure how to interpret your response...

Comment: If you add an unique primary key to the table which in my query I named "ID" you can use my query to achieve what you want.

Comment: I don't have the luxury of adding a key.

Comment: well i just checked and it seems I do have a unique primary key called LEGID.  Seems odd though because LEGID 1 has LEGTRIPNUMBER Q1001 has  and LEGID 2 has LEGTRIPNUMBER Q1001 also..???

Comment: I think this has solved my challenge... THank you

Answer (score 0):

*Which* values of `LEGDATE` & `LEGGROUP` do you want for the distinct `LEGTRIPNUMBER`? there are multiple non-distinct possibilities and the concept of "first occurrence" is only valid with an explicit order.

To get the values where `LEGDATE` is the earliest for example;

```
select Num_Trip_Num, LEGDATE, LEGGROUP from (
    select
       cast(substring(t_RecordkeepingLeg.LEGTRIPNUMBER, 2, 4) as INT) as Num_Trip_Num,
       row_number() over (partition by substring(t_RecordkeepingLeg.LEGTRIPNUMBER, 2, 4) order by t_RecordkeepingLeg.LEGDATE asc) as row,
       t_RecordkeepingLeg.LEGDATE,
       t_RecordkeepingLeg.LEGGROUP
    from t_RecordkeepingLeg
       where left (t_RecordkeepingLeg.LEGTRIPNUMBER, 1) = 'Q'
) T
    where row = 1
```

Comment: As you can see from my input noted above, there are 2 rows for Q1001. I only want to see the first occurrence and the corresponding data for LEGDATE and LEGGROUP on this row.  In this case I want Q1001  08/12/12 0001.  Skip the next row then return the first occurrence of Q1002 along with 09/01/12 0001.

Comment: There is no concept of "first occurrence" unless you sort by something, the example above assumes you want the row with the earliest LEGDATE. Selecting data without an order by is not guaranteed to be in any order.

Comment: What does Select Distinct do?  I thought if there were multiple rows with the same column data it would only select one of them?

Comment: select distinct a,b,c will give 1 row for every unique combination of a,b,c

Comment: Oh I see... I'm getting an education.. thank you.